# Rgd How to Convert cast in php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

```
convert(cast(convert('$username' using  utf8) as binary) using latin1)
```

This is what I do for my MySQL query.

I have a string that is encoded as utf8 recorded into mysql as latin1

Now I draw out the latin1, but I wanna retrieve it as utf8 and display as utf8.

I tried mb_convert, utf8_encode and decode, all to no avail.

How can I restore back the original utf8 with php?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier fixing your table to use the proper charset right away?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Decide which case you have:
[How mangling happens](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#how_mangling_happens_on_insert)

Step 2:  Decide what you want to do.  You seem to want to leave the table messed up but retrieve the data.  It would be better to fix the data, then retrieve the data without contortions.